# Grid/Block Terrain GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I am trying to learn Unity, but i have plenty of experience with C# as a professional developer so this question is solely regarding how to to represent the model in Unity.

I am trying to build a block based terrain with a more finely grained height, my model looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        "x":0,
        "y":0.2,
        "z":0,
        "type": "grass"
    },
    {
        "x":1,
        "y":0.3,
        "z":0,
        "type": "grass"
    },
    {
        "x":0,
        "y":0.1,
        "z":1,
        "type": "stone"
    },
    {
        "x":1,
        "y":0.4,
        "z":1,
        "type": "stone"
    }
]
```

I see 2 options:

1. Create a cube for every block.
2. Build a mesh for the exposed surfaces of all blocks combined together when viewed from above.

1 seems easy to do, but potentially slow, whereas 2 seems like the better approach, but i don't see how to go about applying different textures for each block.

Answer (score 1):

Depending if you are making some kind of Minecraft world or just a simple voxel terrain you could have different solutions.

A simple solution is using quads instead of cubes:
A cube is made of 6 quads, instead of creating each cube, you could create each quad for then exposed surfaces, you keep performance and is easy to implement if it's a simple terrain.

If you want more complex structures like Minecraft does, you could implement more complex algorithms where you create (and update) each polygon in an optimized way, like [Greedy Meshing](https://github.com/roboleary/GreedyMesh) algorithm. [Here](https://eddieabbondanz.io/post/voxel/greedy-mesh/) is a Unity implementation.

Also you may take a look to Unity's [DOTS](https://unity.com/dots) where the Entity Component System promise performance while having a lot of objects.

An [example video](https://youtu.be/ULdGzhRoO1M) of how will look using Unity DOTS + Greedy Meshing.

**EDIT**

I just found a GitHub repo using Unity's DOTS to create a Minecraft style world:

[Voxel Game Prototype in Unity ECS](https://github.com/sarkahn/dots-blockworld)

Comment: So create a quad for each exposed side and apply the texture to that? Doesn't this have the same issue as creating a cube for each block but more so due to the additional GameObjects?

Comment: It has less polygons, so it's maybe one thing for another one. But yes, its not the best solution. So, if you have a more complex structure check the Greedy Meshing algorithm, or the Entity Component System, both are better choices.

Comment: Took a quick look at DOTS, looks like a significant change so will need to spend time reading documentation/watching tutorials before I dive in. Assuming I use that though, would several entities with quads have roughly the same performance as a single mesh with the same number of polygons?

Comment: DOTS it's really a signficant change, but can be worthy depending on the project. About your question, I am not 100% sure but I think that several entities with quads will have better performance than a single mesh with the same number of polygons. Because they share the same mesh data. But again, I am not completly sure, sadly I am not a DOTS expert.